# How to pass variable to css in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I am running angular app, I calculate width of element and store it under variable finalposition and I want to move to left (finalposition)px. I want this style property to be applied only on hovering over the element. How to do this?

**component.ts**

```
 ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
    this.finalposition = document.getElementById('spandiv').offsetWidth;
  }
```

**component.html**

```
  <input id="inputCustome" type="text">
  <p id="spandiv">xyzkskssss</p>
```

**component.css**

```
#inputCustomer {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 7px;
  left: 2px;
}


#spandiv {
  position: absolute;
  right:145px;
  top: 40px;
  background-color: #6B6664;
  padding: 5px;
  color:white;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: block;
  opacity:0;
  overflow: hidden;

}


 #inputCustomer:hover + #spandiv {
  position: absolute;
  left: var(--finalPosition*2)+ "px"; // this value is not getting picked up
  top:40px;
  display: inline;
  opacity:1;

}
```

Comment: Hi, How to apply ngStyle only on hovering

Comment: Have you tried the solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `(mouseenter)` and `(mouseleave)` to set `finalPosition` value.

Try:

```
<input id="inputCustome" type="text" (mouseenter)="finalPosition = finalPosition * 2" (mouseleave) ="finalPosition = finalPosition /2">
<p id="spandiv" [style.left]="finalPosition + 'px'" >xyzkskssss</p>
```

or

```
<input id="inputCustome" type="text" (mouseenter)="finalPosition = finalPosition * 2" (mouseleave) ="finalPosition = finalPosition /2">
<p id="spandiv" [ngStyle]="{'left': finalPosition + 'px'}" >xyzkskssss</p>
```

**[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-smmev7?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage the power of Angular directive to do this kind of stuff. You can also use the Angular events such as `mouseover`, `mouseenter`. For eg.

```
<input id="inputCustome" type="text" (mouseover)="onMouseOver()">
```

or You can use the directive like

```
<div styleHover >Hover me</div>


@Directive({
  selector: '[styleHover]'
})
export class StyleOnHover {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  @HostListener('mouseover') onHover(e) {
    console.log(e)
    console.log(this.el);
    // this.el.style => change the property
  }
}
```

Comment: I like this approach a lot.